# How to style a text script in html?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a hits.php file which passes `$x` variable  into my index.php file which is the hitcounter of my website. I had tried many css styles in hits.php and also in index.php but none of them is worked! Would anyone tells me how to style my php output in index.php?

Hits.php:

```
           <?php
              $counts = ("counter.txt");
              $hits = file($counts);
              $hits[0] ++;
              $fp = fopen($counts, "w");
              fputs($fp , "$hits[0]");
              fclose($fp);
              $x=$hits[0];
              header("Content-type: text/javascript");
              echo "document.write('" . $x . "');";
              ?>
```

Index.php:

```
              <script type="text/javascript" src="hits.php"></script>
```

Comment: there is no need to use a script tag to load the php code, just remove the content type line and change the last line to `<span class="counter"><?= $x =>`, then include that file wherever you want your counter to be. Adding an element and a class will let you target that element in your css rules.

Comment: @JimL didnt get it could u give me and example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had tried this and works!

firstly ,i do not need having variable `.$x.` therefore i will use `.$hits[0].` instead. so the code will be like :

```
      <?php     
          echo '<span class="counter">'.$hits[0].'</span>'; 
      ?>       
        <style type="text/css">
            .counter{
                font-size: 50px;
                color: #ff4d4d;
            }
        </style>
```